# Зачем нужен werf?

Tags: непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-ci, kubernetes, ci-cd, werf

Вопрос конечно пространный и размытый. Но все же.
Вот у нас есть кластер. Вот у нас есть gitlab-ci (например).
Приложение собирается, тесты бегают, деплой проходит.
Вот зачем в эту историю теперь все пихают `werf`? Что он такое привносит чего раньше не было. Мне (с моей нупской точки зрения) он кажется ненужной надстройкой.
Объясните пожалуйста, в чем миссия верфи?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

werf, во-первых, выполняет некоторые конкретные функции (о них см. ниже), а во-вторых, «склеивает» разрозненные компоненты, участвующие в CI/CD (Docker, реестр контейнеров, Helm, Kubernetes и собственно CI-систему), в единую систему.

Конкретные функции:

1. **Сборка**.

Можно:

- просто оставить тот же Dockerfile, что использовался раньше, и продолжать собирать по нему же (он будет совместим с werf);
- перейти на формат самой werf (не так сложно) и получить ряд дополнительных фишек по их оптимизации/ускорению: общий кэш, артефакты, инкрементные сборки по Git-истории, интеграция с Bash-скриптами/Ansible-задачами, удобные инструменты для отладки проблем при сборке…

Безотносительно выбранного пути — есть общие плюсы: параллельная и распределенная сборка, продвинутая система тегирования (content-based tagging). Даже если не так нужны конкретные фичи, факт перевода сборки на werf (в т.ч. и с Dockerfile) позволяет использовать те же образы в последующих этапах их жизни (см. ниже).

1.1. Ещё одна функция, которую можно считать частью сборки, — **публикация** собранного в werf образа **в container registry**. Поддерживается не только Docker Registry, но и другие популярные реализации (включая GitLab Registry, Harbor, облачные решения и т.п.).

2. **Деплой**.

Пожалуй, назвал бы это главной фичей werf — удобный деплой в Kubernetes, интегрированный с другими этапами жизни образов. Внутри для этого используется улучшенная версия Helm (отдельный Helm не потребуется). Образы приложения после их сборки автоматически выкатываются в K8s (Helm-чартами). Важное отличие от Helm — процесс деплоя происходит наглядно, т.е. показывает реальный статус (логи и состояние), и выполняет откат в случае проблем.

В последней версии werf (v1.2) действия сборки и деплоя объединены в одну команду (converge), а заодно сделан упор на GitOps-подход, когда «Git является единым источником правды», т.е. где полностью определено приложение (его исходник, инструкции для сборки, чарты для деплоя), а **werf — это система, которая постоянно (т.е. при каждом новом коммите) приводит Kubernetes в состояние, описанное в этом Git**.

3. **Очистка**.

Образы приложения, которые хранятся в реестре и больше не нужны (не являются релизами, не выкачены где-либо в Kubernetes, не потребуются для откатов), автоматически определяются и очищаются.

Завершающий момент — **все эти функции интегрируются с любой CI-системой**. Есть готовые руководства по интеграции с [GitLab CI](https://ru.werf.io/documentation/advanced/ci_cd/gitlab_ci_cd.html) и [GitHub Actions](https://ru.werf.io/documentation/advanced/ci_cd/github_actions.html), а для остальных — [общая инструкция](https://ru.werf.io/documentation/using_with_ci_cd_systems.html).

Краткое введение, где можно подробнее увидеть, что делает и как вообще работает werf, есть на [сайте проекта](https://ru.werf.io/introduction.html).

**Подводя итог**:

1. С werf можно в **одном месте описать жизненный цикл приложения**: его
   сборку (Dockerfile или аналог) и деплой (инфраструктура в виде
   Helm-чартов), — и утилита (вместе с CI-системой) будет делать так,
   чтобы он выполнялся. Для разработчиков это выглядит так, что при
   каждом новом коммите собираются обновлённые образы, помещаются в
   реестр, деплоятся в Kubernetes. Таким образом, развернутое в
   Kubernetes приложение всегда в актуальном состоянии. Чтобы всё это
   происходило, достаточно Git, werf и предпочтительной CI-системы.
2. Кроме этой унификации/автоматизации, **на всех этапах жизни приложения
   добавляются свои фишк**и: оптимизированная и распределенная сборка,
   отладка и откаты при деплое, очистка старых образов…

P.S. Для разработчиков, которые не очень глубоко погружались в инфраструктуру, есть [онлайн-самоучитель](https://ru.werf.io/applications_guide_ru/) с пошаговым введением в применение werf (и минимально необходимой теорией по сопутствующим вопросам).

Comment: мне понравилось выдача актуальных репортов о стадиях деплоя (в отличии от helm). но в остальном я не понимаю что мне мешает описать (почти) то же самое в gitlab-ci.yml. но я конечно не девопс и взгляд на этот вопрос у меня поверхностный. большое спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Если коротко, миссия верфа: обеспечить соответствие определённому git-коммиту выкаченного приложения в кубе и опубликованных образов в container registry. В версии 1.2 вводится понятие giterminism обозначающего "детерминированность гитом".

Для этой цели помимо прочего:

- образы публикуются по content-based digest-ам, пересобираются только по необходимости;
- гарантируется воспроизводимость content-based digest-ов для произвольных коммитов из git и immutability опубликованных образов;
- обеспечивается отслеживание процесса выката и успешное завершение выката даёт гарантию, что приложение действительно выкатилось, есть возможности конфигурировать этот процесс;
- реализуется продвинутая очистка неиспользуемых образов, основанная на истории git-репозитория приложения (есть возможность очищать старые коммиты, оставить образы для коммитов из веток, плюс сохранить N коммитов истории и проч., подробнее: https://werf.io/documentation/reference/werf_yaml.html#cleanup и https://werf.io/documentation/advanced/cleanup.html).

Werf создаёт целостную систему, которую легко конфигурировать, в которой нажав выкат для какого-то коммита в любой момент времени мы получаем некоторое воспроизводимое состояние.

Реализуется это всё конечно же путём объединения некоторых уже существующих решений (Dockerfile builder, helm), некоторые куски реализуются самостоятельно (оптимизированная сборка образов через stapel-сборщик с инкрементальной пересборкой путём наложения git-патчей, отслеживание деплоя через kubedog, content-based тегирование связанное с git-ом, очистка неиспользуемых образов (реализация для всех возможных имплементаций docker-registry), распределённые блокировки при билде образов и при выкате в кластер, поддержка секретов для helm, поддержка injection-а аннотаций и лейблов для helm, интеграция собранных образов с helm-шаблонами).